# Can't log in. Blinking desktop

Tags: greeter

I can't get past the login screen after starting my computer. The wallpaper blinks shortly, and then I'm out again.

Says no Nvidia graphics adapter found in syslog. I have AMD graphics card, not nvidia.

Comment: I tried this as well, as also can not log in but the Answer above did not help :(
ANy other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this way...
1. Press `ALT-Control-F1` and use ASCII login
2. Type `mv ~/.config ~/.config.old`
3. Press `ALT-Control-F7` to back to the origin screen and login again

Comment: Didn't work. I'm not the only one with this problem. The other one had to reinstall the OS after sitting with this for many hours

Comment: Or reinstall your graphic adapter.

Comment: I created a recovery disk and logged in to the graphical screen for root today. I think this is just a major bug in the log in screen code. Edit: To clarify, I logged in without going through the login screen, so that should rule out other issues.